# Why does Peer.js disconnect after I call connection.send()?

Tags: javascript, peerjs

I'm working on a simple two-way communication website. It uses Peer.js for peer-to-peer browser communication. I've taken a lot of the code from this demo: https://jmcker.github.io/Peer-to-Peer-Cue-System/. The problem is, after I call sendMessage() to send data between the browsers, they get disconnected. The data is sent, I believe, but it is never received, as the connection is cut off as soon as I try to send it. Here's the code for the **host device**:

```
var peer;
var lastPeerId;
var conn;

function initialize() {
    // Create own peer object with connection to shared PeerJS server
    peer = new Peer(null, {
        debug: 0
    });

    peer.on('open', function (id) {
        // Workaround for peer.reconnect deleting previous id
        if (peer.id === null) {
            console.log('Received null id from peer open');
            peer.id = lastPeerId;
        } else {
            lastPeerId = peer.id;
        }

        console.log("ID: " + peer.id);
        console.log("Awaiting connection.")
    });
    peer.on('connection', function (c) {
        // Allow only a single connection
        if (conn) {
            c.on('open', function () {
                c.send("Already connected to another client");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    c.close();
                }, 500);
            });
            return;
        }

        conn = c;
        console.log("Connected to: " + conn.peer);
        ready();
    });
    peer.on('disconnected', function () {
        console.log('Connection lost. Please reconnect');

        // Workaround for peer.reconnect deleting previous id
        peer.id = lastPeerId;
        peer._lastServerId = lastPeerId;
        peer.reconnect();
    });
    peer.on('close', function () {
        conn = null;
        console.log('Connection destroyed');
    });
    peer.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};

function ready() {
    conn.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("Data recieved");
        console.log("Received: " + data);
    });
    conn.on('close', function () {
        console.log("Connection reset. Awaiting connection...");
        conn = null;
        //start(true);
    });
}

function sendMessage(message) {
    if (conn && conn.open) {
        conn.send(message);
        console.log("Sent: " + message);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection is closed');
    }
}

initialize();
```

And this is the code for the **connecting device (not the host)**:

```
var peer;
var lastPeerId;
var conn;
//Get the ID specified in the address after the "?" sign
var idToConnectTo = window.location.href.split("?")[1];

function initialize() {
    // Create own peer object with connection to shared PeerJS server
    peer = new Peer(null, {
        debug: 0
    });

    peer.on('open', function (id) {
        // Workaround for peer.reconnect deleting previous id
        if (peer.id === null) {
            console.log('Received null id from peer open');
            peer.id = lastPeerId;
        } else {
            lastPeerId = peer.id;
        }

        console.log('ID: ' + peer.id);
        join();
    });
    peer.on('disconnected', function () {
        console.log('Connection lost. Please reconnect');

        // Workaround for peer.reconnect deleting previous id
        peer.id = lastPeerId;
        peer._lastServerId = lastPeerId;
        peer.reconnect();
    });
    peer.on('close', function () {
        conn = null;
        console.log('Connection destroyed');
    });
    peer.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};

function join() {
    // Close old connection
    if (conn) {
        conn.close();
    }

    // Create connection to destination peer specified in the input field
    conn = peer.connect(idToConnectTo, {
        reliable: true
    });

    conn.on('open', function () {
        console.log("Connected to: " + conn.peer);
    });

    // Handle incoming data
    conn.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("Received: " + data);
    });
    conn.on('close', function () {
        console.log("Connection closed");
    });
};

function sendMessage(message) {
    if (conn && conn.open) {
        conn.send(message);
        console.log("Sent: " + message);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection is closed');
    }
}

initialize();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that I was trying to communicate between two tabs of the same browser. When using two different browsers it worked correctly.